# How to solve a big number of problems automatically in AMPL?

Tags: ampl

i have a big number of problems (app 5000 instances) that i want to solve in ampl and i like to do it in one run in a for loop. I know how to reset the data and how to make a loop, but i don't know if you can make a name and then call the data from that name, like you can do in C with "printf" and then open the text with that.

I'm thinking if i can't change the name automatically in ampl, call ampl from C with "system()" and change the data file in C.

My question is if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using AMPL script, for example:

```
for {i in 1..5000}
  shell('ampl problem' & i & '.ampl');
```

This will run ampl on `problem1.ampl`, ... `problem5000.ampl`.

The `shell` command is similar to the `system` function in C and other languages. It is described in the [AMPL book](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/24-refman.pdf#page=43).

Comment: I solve it using system() in C to call ampl and changing a "data.dat" file automatically in C for all the instances that i had. Thanks, now i know how to do it in ampl.